# CartoDB basemaps -how to clear out?

Tags: carto, tiles, basemap, xyz

In CartoDB, when I switch to Map View on any of my tables, I have the opportunity to change the basemap, including using "Yours".  In my attempts to connect to our MassGIS XYZ basemaps, I've filled up all 8 slots and I can't figure out how to clear these out?

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I just didn't see that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a little arrow in the bottom right of each custom baselayer thumbnail; click it and select "Remove Base Layer".